# Search table on only one column Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code which can search my entire table however I only want to search the first column.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mySearch").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`:nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector:

```
$("#myTable tr td:nth-child(1)")
```

`:nth-child()` allows you to filter your selection to elements at the specified index.  If you want to search one "*column*" only, what you want is the `<td>` in the designated position of each row, so it's important to include `td` in your selector.

Comment: That searches only in the first column but doesn't hide the entire row if no match as seen in this image: https://imgur.com/a/YIFZlsz Thanks

Comment: It also removes the heading when searching. My headings have <thead> and my entries have <tbody> tags

Comment: The first answer had the same problem. I only want to search in the first column but the search to hide/show entire row.

Comment: sorry I changed my comment — not exactly clear on your condition but the key is to use `parent()` since `$(this)` is refering to the `td` and you want to jump up to the `tr` if you want to manipulate the row.

Comment: your original comments code did what i wanted, the new code shows nothing when searching.

Comment: ok - I just added `parent()` to your selection: `$(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)`

Comment: I don't quite understand why you have the comparison as an argument inside of `toggle()` though — isn't that meant to set a duration for your animation?

Comment: not sure i based it off the tutorial on jquery filtering tables at w3schools